# Populate and return entities from DownloadStringCompleted handler in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am having a method which fetches HTML from a url, extracts entities by parsing it, and returns List of entites. Here is *sample* code:

```
  public List<Entity> FetchEntities()
    {
        List<Entity> myList = new List<Entity>();
        string url = "<myUrl>";
        string response = String.Empty;
        client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            response = e.Result;
            // parse response
            // extract content and generate entities
            // <---- I am currently filling list here
        };
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));

        return myList;
    }
```

The problem is while async call is in progress control returns with empty `myList`. How can I prevent this. My ultimate goal is to return *filled* list.

And also this method is in a seperate class library project and being called from windows phone application and I *have to* keep it like that only. Is there any way to do this or I am missing something? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either pass callback to the method like this and make it async without Tasks, so u have to update method usage slightly.

```
public void FetchEntities(
    Action<List<Entity>> resultCallback, 
    Action<string> errorCallback)
{
    List<Entity> myList = new List<Entity>();
    string url = "<myUrl>";
    string response = String.Empty;
    client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        response = e.Result;
        // parse response
        // extract content and generate entities
        // <---- I am currently filling list here

        if (response == null)
        {
            if (errorCallback != null)
                errorCallback("Ooops, something bad happened");
        }
        else
        {
            if (callback != null)
                callback(myList);
        }
    };
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
}
```

The other option is to force it be synchronous. Like that

```
public List<Entity> FetchEntities()
{
    List<Entity> myList = new List<Entity>();
    string url = "<myUrl>";
    string response = String.Empty;
    client = new WebClient();
    AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        response = e.Result;
        // parse response
        // extract content and generate entities
        // <---- I am currently filling list here

        waitHandle.Set();
    };
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));

    waitHandle.WaitOne();

    return myList;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That is the point of asynchronous programming to be non-blocking. You can pass a callback as a parameter and handle the result somewhere else instead of trying to return it.

If you need to return the result you can use [this TPL library](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks), I've been using it without problem for a while now.

```
public Task<string> GetWebResultAsync(string url)
     {
         var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
         var client = new WebClient();

         DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler h = null;
         h = (sender, args) =>
                 {
                     if (args.Cancelled)
                     {
                         tcs.SetCanceled();
                     }
                     else if (args.Error != null)
                     {
                         tcs.SetException(args.Error);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         tcs.SetResult(args.Result);
                     }

                     client.DownloadStringCompleted -= h;
                 };

         client.DownloadStringCompleted += h;
         client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));

         return tcs.Task;
     }
}
```

And calling it is exactly how you use TPL in .net 4.0

```
GetWebResultAsnyc(url).ContinueWith((t) => 
                                    {
                                         t.Result //this is the downloaded string
                                    });
```

or:

```
var downloadTask = GetWebResultAsync(url);
downloadTask.Wait();
var result = downloadTask.Result; //this is the downloaded string
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am trying to use above method, I've added the package `System.Threading.Tasks` and having reference to `System.Threading.Tasks.WP71` in project, but not able to resolve `Task` and `TaskCompletionSource`. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: You should reference System.Threading.Tasks instead of System.Threading.Tasks.WP71 EDIT: the assembly itself is called System.Threading.Tasks.WP71 and in the code add a using statement: using System.Threading.Tasks;

Comment: Yes, I tried that, it's saying couldnot resolve type `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions`. How can I handle this?

Comment: Thanks, the Lib worked, but having another issue. I am calling your method as : `var result = GetWebResultAsync(url); string html = result.Result;` Is this correct? since, the 2nd statement is not getting hit. Also I am not able to find any examples for this lib.

Comment: you don't need to search for this specific library, any task parallel library example would apply. Also updated my answer to show how to call it.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried as your solution, but I am always getting result `Null`. But on other dummy console aplication using `DownloadString()` (not Async), I am getting html. Any ideas?

Comment: The result will be null when there is an exception or the task is cancelled or you are checking the result before it is finished. set some break points and check what happens.

Comment: OK, just tried with another urls, no errors but still how should I *wait* for result? I tried `RunSynchronously()` method, also `while` looping untill `.IsCompleted`, but even if `.IsCompleted` is true and no errors, the `result` is `null`. :( Please help me.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure why it's not working for you. I've been using exactly this code in few apps without any problems. I'll update my answer if I find something helpful.